# Windows/CMD | How to break line if e.g. character count reached?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-line-interface

I wrote a batch file where I put in a bunch of text that gets set to some variable and then next line echoes that variable into a text file.

Problem is that it echoes all of it into one long line and it's impossible to read (it forces you to toggle wrap mode, but what if software doesn't support it).

```
echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at elit eu felis gravida pretium. Morbi suscipit eu metus quis facilisis. Sed aliquet eget sem ac semper. Fusce tempor magna dui, nec ullamcorper nulla rutrum eget. Suspendisse mattis lorem ut nulla placerat vestibulum. Vivamus sollicitudin nisl in lorem suscipit luctus. Nam a nisi vestibulum, lacinia nulla faucibus, condimentum eros. Donec fringilla neque et massa sagittis sollicitudin. Pellentesque vestibulum, metus maximus lacinia varius, nisi tortor facilisis ante, et porttitor magna urna sed odio. Maecenas ut mi sed ipsum pretium mattis et a urna. Nunc vulputate ornare bibendum. Pellentesque libero lacus, porttitor ut sem vitae, lobortis dictum erat. Sed viverra euismod nisl, nec malesuada turpis pellentesque eget." > text_file.txt
```

(just look at this example, it's unreadable)

So I need to print it into something like:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at elit
 eu felis gravida pretium. Morbi suscipit eu metus quis facilisis. Sed 
aliquet eget sem ac semper. Fusce tempor magna dui, nec ullamcorper nulla 
rutrum eget. Suspendisse mattis lorem ut nulla placerat vestibulum. Vivamus 
sollicitudin nisl in lorem suscipit luctus. Nam a nisi vestibulum, lacinia 
nulla faucibus, condimentum eros. Donec fringilla neque et massa sagittis 
sollicitudin. Pellentesque vestibulum, metus maximus lacinia varius, nisi 
tortor facilisis ante, et porttitor magna urna sed odio. Maecenas ut mi sed 
ipsum pretium mattis et a urna. Nunc vulputate ornare bibendum. Pellentesque 
libero lacus, porttitor ut sem vitae, lobortis dictum erat. Sed viverra 
euismod nisl, nec malesuada turpis pellentesque eget."
```

As you can see, the longest line is `76` characters. Is it possible to use it as a breakpoint or something?

But that would also mean it can't chop it in the middle of the word.

UPDATE: I found same question and answer on Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60219/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-insert-line-breaks-into-a-long-string the command is called `fold`. Any alternative to Windows?

Comment: You need to program a method to cut the string at a space previous to the maximum allowed length, and repeat this procedure as long as there is a remaining string. If you have problems with this method, please post here your code an we gladly help you...

Comment: What method? You just  wrote a theory. I don't even know how to count characters and then break at it like I asked it in the question.

Comment: You asked for a Windows tool similar to the Unix tool `fold`, which is off topic. It is also essential that you at least provide the batch file referenced in your first paragraph.

Comment: @Combo the very first line is my all code it echoes long text to a file. And I'm looking how to add such feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I wrote something like this about 4 years ago when I was first starting to learn batch. It almost certainly doesn't accept `&`s or `)`s, but you don't have any in your sample text and I don't care enough to test for them.

Pass the string in as a single parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cls
set unformattedText=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at elit eu felis gravida pretium. Morbi suscipit eu metus quis facilisis. Sed aliquet eget sem ac semper. Fusce tempor magna dui, nec ullamcorper nulla rutrum eget. Suspendisse mattis lorem ut nulla placerat vestibulum. Vivamus sollicitudin nisl in lorem suscipit luctus. Nam a nisi vestibulum, lacinia nulla faucibus, condimentum eros. Donec fringilla neque et massa sagittis sollicitudin. Pellentesque vestibulum, metus maximus lacinia varius, nisi tortor facilisis ante, et porttitor magna urna sed odio. Maecenas ut mi sed ipsum pretium mattis et a urna. Nunc vulputate ornare bibendum. Pellentesque libero lacus, porttitor ut sem vitae, lobortis dictum erat. Sed viverra euismod nisl, nec malesuada turpis pellentesque eget.
set width=76
set counter=0
set slashN=^


if not [%1]==[] set unformattedText=%~1

:wordCounter
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%A in ("%unformattedText%") do (
    if not "%%A"=="" (
        set words[!counter!]=%%A
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        set unformattedText=%%B
        goto wordCounter
    ) else (
        goto loopBreak
    )
)

:loopBreak
echo There are !counter! words in your sentence.

set /a counter=!counter!-1
for /l %%A in (0,1,!counter!) do (
    echo !words[%%A]!>tmp.txt
    for %%J in (tmp.txt) do (
        set /a len[%%A]=%%~zJ
        set /a len[%%A]-=2
        del tmp.txt
        if !len[%%A]! gtr %width% set /a width=!len[%%A]!+1
    )
)

:: -- Concatenate the words and spaces --
set newString=
set stringLength=0
for /l %%A in (0,1,!counter!) do (
    if %%A lss !counter! (
        set /a possLength=!stringLength!+!len[%%A]!+1

        if !possLength! leq %width% (
            set newString=!newString!!words[%%A]! 
            set /a stringLength+=!len[%%A]!+1
        ) else (
            set newString=!newString!!slashN!!words[%%A]! 
            set /a stringLength=!len[%%A]!+1
        )
    ) else (
        set /a possLength=!stringLength!+!len[%%A]!

        if !possLength! leq %width% (
            set newString=!newString!!words[%%A]!
            set /a stringLength+=!len[%%A]!
        ) else (
            set newString=!newString!!slashN!!words[%%A]!
            set /a stringLength=!len[%%A]!
        )
    )
)

echo !newString!
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my version...

**EDIT**: I modified the code, so the split method is now isolated in a subroutine that may be called by any program.

The subroutine cut the string at a space previous to the maximum allowed length, and repeat this procedure as long as there is a remaining string.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set longString="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at elit eu felis gravida pretium. Morbi suscipit eu metus quis facilisis. Sed aliquet eget sem ac semper. Fusce tempor magna dui, nec ullamcorper nulla rutrum eget. Suspendisse mattis lorem ut nulla placerat vestibulum. Vivamus sollicitudin nisl in lorem suscipit luctus. Nam a nisi vestibulum, lacinia nulla faucibus, condimentum eros. Donec fringilla neque et massa sagittis sollicitudin. Pellentesque vestibulum, metus maximus lacinia varius, nisi tortor facilisis ante, et porttitor magna urna sed odio. Maecenas ut mi sed ipsum pretium mattis et a urna. Nunc vulputate ornare bibendum. Pellentesque libero lacus, porttitor ut sem vitae, lobortis dictum erat. Sed viverra euismod nisl, nec malesuada turpis pellentesque eget."

rem To show lines in screen:
call :splitLines longString 76

rem To store lines in a file:
call :splitLines longString 76 > file.txt

goto :EOF


:splitLines string width
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=!%~1!"

:nextLine
   set /A "i=%~2+1"

   :prevChar
      set /A i-=1
   if "!string:~%i%,1!" neq " " goto prevChar

   echo !string:~0,%i%!

   set /A i+=1
   set "string=!string:~%i%!"
if "!string:~%~2!" neq "" goto nextLine

echo !string!
exit /B
```

Comment: Breaks on echo !string! > file.txt

Comment: Hey thanks for hard work, but if you add 'pause' it prints all text with 'Press any key to continue . . .' at the end, which means it doesn't print just the text inside the variable to the file, it prints everything what's in console.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... Does not my code works as intended? If you modify the code, then you should know what you are doing; otherwise, how could I fix an "error" introduced by _you_? Note that all output generated in `:splitLines` subroutine is redirected to the file (this is the purpose of this line: `call :splitLines longString 76 > file.txt` BTW). If you want that `pause` command be displayed in the screen, then just do it: `pause > CON`!